# Why does docker login hang on Travis CI?

Tags: docker, travis-ci

I have a `.travis.yml` using Trusty Beta VMs which tries to push to the Docker hub. The relevant sections are:

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty

language: cpp

compiler:
    - gcc

services:
    - docker

env:
    global:
        - secure: "i...=" # DOCKER_EMAIL
        - secure: "Z...=" # DOCKER_USER
        - secure: "p...=" # DOCKER_PASSWORD

<snip>

after_success:
    - docker login -e $DOCKER_EMAIL -u $DOCKER_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD
    - make docker-r-deliver
```

The log is giving me:

```
<snip>

Setting environment variables from .travis.yml
$ export DOCKER_EMAIL=[secure]
$ export DOCKER_USER=[secure]
$ export DOCKER_PASSWORD=[secure]

<snip>

$ docker login -e $DOCKER_EMAIL -u $DOCKER_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD
Password: 
No output has been received in the last 10m0s, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.
The build has been terminated
```

There is a similar issue here: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5387. But I don't think that is it - my password contains no special characters. I tried the `docker login` in `before_install` - same issue, except weirdly, it prompted for username.

**Edit**

`docker login -e foo@example.com -u fooo -p barty` does not hang (gives expected `Error response from daemon: Wrong login/password, please try again`), suggesting something is up with the env vars.

**Edit**

Well, this is embarrassing, I was setting `DOCKER_USER` but attempting to use `DOCKER_USERNAME`! That would do it!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the exact syntax given in the [TravisCI documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/#Pushing-a-Docker-Image-to-a-Registry)?

> `docker login -e="$DOCKER_EMAIL" -u="$DOCKER_USERNAME" -p="$DOCKER_PASSWORD"`

Comment: Thanks @Thomasleveil : yes tried that first up but same problem, that is why I simplified it to what I use locally. But I may try it again. It's a slow debugging process...

Answer (score 1):

My bad! As per edit, I was setting `DOCKER_USER` but attempting to use `DOCKER_USERNAME`!